# Sencha opposite of Ext.getCmp('mainpage').add({items:stuff});

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have used the following to add content to my view:
`Ext.getCmp('mainpage').add({items:thecarousel});`

*thecarousel* is an array representing my carousel and its content. This all works as I require it to. Here's the code for it:

```
var thecarousel = { 
                   xtype: 'carousel',
                   width: '100%',
                   height: '100%',
                   itemId: 'thecarousel',
                   id: 'carousel',
                   defaults: {
                       styleHtmlContent:true,
                         },

                         items: allcharts, 
                        }

                Ext.getCmp('mainpage').add({items:thecarousel});
                Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);// remove loading message`
```

What I am looking for is an method to do the opposite of this and remove the carousel from the view.`

I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

1. Ext.getCmp('mainpage').remove('carousel',false)
2. Ext.getCmp('mainpage').remove({items:'carousel'})
3. Ext.getCmp('mainpage').remove('carousel',true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `id: 'carousel'`, you can do that like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('mainpage').remove(Ext.getCmp('carousel'))
```

You could also do it using a component query:

```
var main = Ext.getCmp('mainpanel');
main.remove(main.down('#carousel'));//added missing closing brackets
//OR, if there is only one component of xtype 'carousel' on your mainpanel:
main.remove(main.down('carousel'));
```

I personally would avoid using IDs and go with the second method (you could give the carousel an `itemId: 'carousel'` and still use `main.remove(main.down('#carousel'))` if you want).

Comment: thanks for this. I tried all of your suggestions and none worked. I will have to keep looking.

Comment: Post your code for `thecarousel`.  My answer should work fine depending on how this is setup.

Comment: Try adding the carousel with just `Ext.getCmp('mainpage').add(thecarousel);`.  You are unnecessarily wrapping it in a container right now.